# IDA pro script to extract all the instructions into a assemble file

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, disassembly, ida

I am looking for some IDA pro scripts to extract all the instructions and write them into a  assemble file, which can be **re-assembly**

Could anyone give me some help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`File -> Produce File -> Create ASM File ...` Shortcut is <kbd>ALT-F10</kbd>

Comment: Hi Devolus, it seems that lots of edit work should be done if I use the asm file generated by "Create ASM File"... and I have no idea what can I do towards this issue... could you give me some help towards how to recompile this asm file...thank you!

Comment: I never produced a really workable output, at best I used it for reference. I'm not convinced that the target ASm is really assembleable, without a lot of work anyway. I doubt that you would get a better output with a script, and you would have to write it first.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this via IDApython:

```
idc.GenerateFile(idc.OFILE_ASM, idc.GetInputFile()+".asm", 0, idc.BADADDR, 0)
```

This answer was found to a previous question found [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3395/ida-pro-ida-python-producing-file-via-terminal). This answer also shows how to generate instruction when IDA only recognizes it as a binary file. This will help immensely at efficiently removing the gibberish that IDA produces. It utilizes the `MakeCode()` function. This will be more efficient because it eliminates the need to manually find all the entry points and hit "c" x numbers of times.